# How to make Console give random number 1-10 C# Unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I am new at C#.
Now I am just truing to make Unity to give me random from 1 - 10.

I am trying to use some examples from internet, but my Unity do not allow to use them.
It often say like "The name 'Console' does not exist in the current context". And I knew that Console.WriteLine exists in C# dictionary.

I am trued to avoid it.

But it still do not work :(

"Assets\scripts\uzd1.cs(11,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
Assets\scripts\uzd1.cs(5,19): error CS1513: } expected" it says.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namsepace Numbers {
    public int RandomNumber(int min, int max)    
    {    
        Random random = new Random();    
        return random.Next(1, 10);    
    }    
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjzpm.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You haven't declared a class. You've declared a *namespace* but no class within it. I suspect all the examples you've found *have* got classes in.

Comment: (And you have a typo for the keyword "namespace" as well.)